# Javascript Problem

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to execute a script in a div tag by AJAX. But in the div tag the script does not run.
Here is my Code:

```
<div id="div0" align="right">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    alert("Hi");
  -->
  </script>
</div>
```

It does not work for me. Please anybody tell me, what is the problem?

Edit:

My complete code is that:

```
<html>  
   <head>  
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var xmlhttp;
      function loadXMLDoc(url)
      {
        xmlhttp=null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for Firefox, Opera, IE7, etc.
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if (xmlhttp!=null)
        {
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=state_Change;
          xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
          xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
        else
        {
          alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
        }
      }

     function state_Change()
     {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
      {// 4 = "loaded"
        if (xmlhttp.status==200)
        {// 200 = "OK"
         document.getElementById('T1').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
          alert("Problem retrieving data:" + xmlhttp.statusText);
        }
     }
   }
   </script>
   </head>

   <body onload="loadXMLDoc('test_xmlhttp.php')">
     <div id="T1"></div><br />
   </body>

  </html>
```

My test_xmlhttp.php is as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    alert("Hi");
  -->
  </script>
```

I want an alert box shows **Hi** when the AJAX is completed. But Nothing happens. Please Please Please give me a solution.

Comment: Trying to show a what in a tag? Also, that code works just fine.

Comment: I forgot to tell that I am trying to use this in AJAX. This does not work in AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function in your state_Change function as below:

```
document.getElementById('T1').innerHTML=eval('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use HTML elements(eg. >) instead of greater-than (>) or less-than (<) characters.
Try following code.

```
<div id="div0" align="right">  <br />
  &lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt; <br />
  &lt;!--  <br />
    alert("Hi");  <br />
  --&gt;  <br />
  &lt;/script&gt;  <br />
</div>   <br />
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be the HTML comments, which should be commented out as S.Mark points out.

*However*, there is no reason to include those comments whatsoever.  They were originally suggested to prevent browsers without JavaScript/JScript support from breaking on the code (trying to read it as markup).  I think the last browsers with that problem came out in like '95 and are no longer in use :)

There is a legit reason to use CDATA blocks if you're serving an XHTML 1.0 Strict document, but I doubt you're going for that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are running it locally and your browser is preventing the javascript from being run?

I just ran the code on my site and it loads up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of failing in this. I tried it on IE8 and Firefox. IE8 blocks it. But once the block is removed, it works fine. Have you noticed any blockage by IE?